# Regex to select a file extension

Tags: python, regex, file-extension, strip

I have an apk file say MyApp.apk. I was trying to strip the .apk extension using the `strip` function in python. But the problem is, If my applications name is WhatsApp.apk then the function strips the letters `pp` also and outputs `WhatsA`. What Regex should I use to strip exactly the `.apk` away?

Comment: You must be misunderstanding how `strip` works. In your case, it probably is removing *all of the characters* `a`, `p`, `k`, and `.`, rather than "the file extension". (I 'm only guessing here, because you tell what you did but did not include the actual code.)

Comment: Use `os.path.splitext`.

Comment: @JoelCornett That's the answer I started posting :) But then I got the idea that he already has the filename :)

Comment: @Jongware Thank you for making my concept on `strip` further clear. I was mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use regex? If you only want the filename then this code will do

```
filename = 'MyApp.apk'
filename = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[0]

print filename
```

output:

```
MyApp
```

Comment: oops, made a typo, I forgot the array index

Comment: I +1'd, but you might want to limit the amount of times the filename is split: `"My.Awesome.App.apk"` would end up being `"My"`, otherwise.

Comment: While helpful, this doesn't address the original posters question or title pertaining to a regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish this if you are certain that all the files end with `.apk` without using the `string.replace` function as

```
>>> str.replace('.apk','')
'MyApp'
```

A solution using `re.sub` would be like

```
>>> import re
>>> str="MyApp.apk"
>>> re.sub('r[\.[^.]+$','',str)
'MyApp.apk'
```

- `\.[^.]+` matches a `.` followed by  anything other than `.` till end of string

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
x="MyApp.apk"
print re.sub(r"\..*$","",x)
```

Answer (score 1):

For filenames i suggest using [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

```
filename = "test.txt"
os.path.splitext(filename)
# ('test', '.txt')
```

If you are using `filename.split()` as other answers suggest you may get in trouble :

```
filename = "this.is.a.file.txt"
filename.split(".")
#['this', 'is', 'a', 'file', 'txt']
os.path.splitext(filename)
#('this.is.a.file', '.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle filenames with `.`s in them, you can do:

```
filename = 'My.App.apk'
filename = '.'.join(filename.split('.')[:-1])

print filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the lightning response. I found another solution too.

```
>>> import os
>>> fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext('/path/to/MyApp.apk')
>>> fileName
'/path/to/MyApp'
>>> fileExtension
'.apk'
```

Comment: And you can use `os.path.basename` to separate the path from the filename.